# Is it possible to have custom avoidance details for Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API allows you to avoid tolls, ferries, and other such common annoyances.  Is there some way to have the routing engine avoid specific places?   I want to take a list of places from the Places API and then create a route that avoids them ... sort of the opposite of waypoints.

Possible?  Or do I need to write my own algorithm for this?

It's basically a yes/no.  Either the routing engine can take this info (show me how), or it can't.  Apparently the answer is "No, it can't" according to the comment below and this is now solved.

Comment: [Feature request in the issue tracker: Issue 214: Ability to influence Directions (e.g. "avoid" / "roadblock")](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)

Comment: If that was an answer I would mark it.   That is exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Feature request in the issue tracker:

- [Issue 214: Ability to influence Directions (e.g. "avoid" / "roadblock")](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)